# Recursively modifying values of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I need to loop through every element of a multidimensional array and modify the contents.   I am using array_walk_recursive for this, but am having a small problem.

Example:

```
$arr = array('cat'=>'cool', 2=>array('something'=>"<script>alert('hello');</script> hello!"));
print_r($arr); // something bad pops up
```

So, using this:

```
function scrub_array($value, $key)
{
    $value = scrub_string($value);
}
```

I invoke:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'scrub_array');
```

Then

```
print_r($arr);
```

The nasty pop-up still appears.  I know `scrub_string()` works as it removes the javascript when applied directly.

What is wrong with the code that the array value is not being modified?

Comment: `function scrub_array($value, $key)` -> `function scrub_array(&$value, $key)`

Comment: Thanks, please post as answer for credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123)'s answer from the comments:

```
function scrub_array($value, $key) -> function scrub_array(&$value, $key)
```